# VBA script to copy Data from specfic cell range and paste to a specific cell in a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following script and am trying to work out how to paste the copied data to cell AA1 in sheet TEST, But before it pastes the selected data i need to clear all the data that is in columns AA:AK in sheet TEST. The script copies the data ok but i can't get Selection.PasteSpecial to work with "offset", and i cant work out how to clear the contents of AA:AK in advance.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Sub CopyDATA()

```
' Set Auto Filter
Selection.AutoFilter
Sheets("SBC_Month").Select
Range("$AA$1:$AK$5000").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="Rep Name"   ' Filters by Rep Name

' copy filtered data
Range("AA1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy

' Paste to sheet Test
Sheets("TEST").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial , Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use

```
Sub CopyDATA()

    Sheets("TEST").Range("AA:AK").ClearContents

    Range("B1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy

    ' Paste to sheet Test
    Sheets("TEST").Range("AA1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```